# Grad is very small

Tags: python, optimization, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm

First I thought, there is no update after the loss calculation and update step but the follwing code gives me false which prove there is an update:

```
before = list(model.parameters())[0].clone()
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
after = list(model.parameters())[0].clone()
logging.info(torch.equal(before.data, after.data))
```

Then I wanted to see the magnitude of chage by the following code:

```
list(model.parameters())[0].grad
```

Which give me very small amaount of change:

```
tensor([[ 3.2294e-07,  7.3983e-06,  6.5637e-06,  ..., -1.3529e-06,
2019-11-16T17:21:03.747068480Z          -4.9979e-06,  4.9799e-06],
2019-11-16T17:21:03.747074966Z         [ 5.5463e-08,  3.0771e-06, -9.5087e-07,  ...,  1.9265e-06,
2019-11-16T17:21:03.747080687Z          -4.5251e-06, -7.1564e-07].....]
```

Here is my model :

```
self.lstm_hidden_dim = lstm_hidden_dim
self.lstm = nn.LSTM(word_embedding_dim,lstm_hidden_dim, num_layers=1,batch_first=False,bidirectional=True)
self.firstHidden = nn.Linear(lstm_hidden_dim*2, 300)
self.relu=nn.ReLU()
self.secondlinear=nn.Linear(300, score_space_size)
self.softmax= nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)
```

Loss function and optimizer:

```
loss_function = nn.NLLLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)
```

Any idea, why the grad is very small?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the parameters up, to see, how much they change each time the optimizer is called.
Therefore you can use a function like this.

```
def read_params(self):
    params=[]
    names=[]
    for name,param in self.lstm.named_parameters():
        params.append(torch.sum(param.data).detach().cpu().numpy())
        names.append(name)
    return params, names

old_weights = np.array(nets.read_params()[0])
#some point later
new_weights = np.array(nets.read_params()[0])
print("weights updated",np.sum(np.abs(old_weights - new_weights)))
```

You can also increase the learning rate by a few magnitudes, to see if it helps.